# java interface methods usage

Tags: java, interface, implementation

Hi I have been given the following interface and I need to implement bag using this interface, I'm a little confuse as how to use the methods, any help/hint would be appreciated. I need to add items to the bag and it should be able to accept duplicate items. Then I have remove an item and find an item.

```
public interface Things<T> extends Iterable<T> {
    public int size();
    public boolean add(T x);
    public T remove(T x);
    public T find(T x);
    public void clear();
}
//Implementing thing using bag
public class Bag<T> implements Things<T> {

    @Override
    public int size() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String add(T x) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String remove(T x) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String find(T x) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}


public class ThingsDemo {


    public static void main(String args[])

    {
        How to I use add(), remove(), and find method here?


    }

}
```

Comment: If you are confused and don't know where to start, then StackOverflow is not the place to ask.  You should be talking to your professor or his/her teaching assistant.  StackOverflow is not a tutorial site and does not provide basic training or code-writing service.

Comment: Use things you've learned in prior work in your course.  Once you've got some code that you think is close, post it here and you may get more help.

Comment: @user6027133 - Stackoverflow is not intended to do your homework for you. Being rude does not change that. If allowed by your instructor and school, you can ask a specific question about your implementation so far. Please see ["How do I ask and answer homework questions"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Comment: I did not asked to do my homework sir, I just asked for a help/hint and in this case I believe it's not me who's rude it's you and your other friend who have no heart to even provide a hint. This is what is rudeness is. Look at the few other people below, they didn't do my homework but provided hint only and that's what I needed to move on.

Comment: @user6027133 you might be better off Googling how interface works and is used. If you have confusion in understanding there, you can come here and ask that question. That question, I'm sure, will help others (if hasn't been asked before) and will also allow you to learn better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public interface Things<T> extends Iterable<T> {
    public int size();
    public boolean add(T x);
    public T remove(T x);
    public T find(T x);
    public void clear();
}
//Implementing thing using bag
public class Bag<T> implements Things<T> {
    private ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T x) {
        list.add(x);
    }

    @Override
    //It's weird why the remove method returns T
    //Sine you already pass x of type T as parameter
    public T remove(T x) {
        list.remove(x);
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public T find(T x) {
        //Since you already know x, what is find() searching for?
        return null;
    }

}


public class ThingsDemo {


    public static void main(String args[])

    {
        Bag<String> bag = new Bag<>();
        bag.add("cat");  
        bag.remove("cat");
    }
}
```

Comment: A better solution. use interface instead of class. Interface driven development.

Answer (score -1):

Here you go. You should not be using String return type inside your bag class. it should be similar to what you have declared inside interface. see add method for sample and implemented the remove and other method similarly.

```
public interface Things<T> extends Iterable<T> {
    public int size();
    public boolean add(T x);
    public T remove(T x);
    public T find(T x);
    public void clear();
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Bag<T> implements Things<T> {

List<T> data = new ArrayList<T>();

@Override
public int size() {
    data.size();
}

@Override
public boolean add(T x) {
    data.add(x);
    return false;
}

@Override
public T remove(T x) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public T find(T x) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void clear() {

}

@Override
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return null;
}
}

public class ThingsDemo {


public static void main(String args[])

{
    Things<String> things = new Bag<>();

    things.add("something");
    System.out.println(things.size());
    things.remove("something");
    System.out.println(things.size());

   }

}
```